# Hard time understanding pipeline functions (map,reduce,filter,lambda)

Tags: python

The function gets 2 arguments, both are sequences.
The first contain sequence of `(course,AVGgrades)`,
the second contain sequence of `(course,factor)`.

The function need to add the factor only to the courses that in the 2nd sequence
and return the updated sequence.
**(loops are not allowed, i need to use map,filter,reduce and labmda)**

For example:

```
courses = (('a', [81, 78, 57])), ('b', [95, 98]), ('c', [75, 45]), ('d', [58]) 
factors = (('c', 15), ('a', 20))
```

The function returns:

```
(('a', 92.0), ('b', 96.5), ('c', 75.0), ('d', 58.0))
```

I managed to calculate the AVG for each course:

```
def avg_grades(courses):
    def calcAVG(courseGrades):
        return sum(courseGrades) / len(courseGrades)  # Calculate average grade for a single course

    coursesGrades = tuple(map(lambda course: (course[0],calcAVG(course[1])), courses))
    return coursesGrades
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map`, `filter` and `lambda` functions.

Here is the solution

```py
def update_courses(courses, factors):
    courses_in_factors = set(map(lambda x: x[0], factors))

    courses_to_update = filter(lambda x: x[0] in courses_in_factors, courses)

    updated_courses = map(lambda course: (course[0], sum(course[1]) / len(course[1]) + factors_dict[course[0]]), courses_to_update)

    updated_courses_list = list(updated_courses)
    other_courses = filter(lambda x: x[0] not in courses_in_factors, courses)
    updated_courses_list.extend(other_courses)

    return tuple(updated_courses_list)

# Test the function
courses = (('a', [81, 78, 57]), ('b', [95, 98]), ('c', [75, 45]), ('d', [58]))
factors = (('c', 15), ('a', 20))

factors_dict = dict(factors)

# Should output (('a', 92.0), ('c', 75.0), ('b', [95, 98]), ('d', [58]))
print(update_courses(courses, factors))
```